# Documentation topic menu: Red dashed border?

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, design

What's this?

> [image]

On [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/2084/unary-operators) for example, there's an red dashed outline on the edit buttons. Same for other topics.
Why is that there, what does it mean?

That '95 outline feels completely out of place in SO's slick design.

I feel it should be replaced with something more subtle, including an title that explains *why* the topic appears to require attention. If the topic doesn't require attention, the border should probably be disabled altogether. This feels like a bug.

Comment: For a full '95 experience it needs more [blinking](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/278564/158100) ...

Comment: On a more serious note: I guess users didn't notice it beforehand and they decided to do a ... *quick hack*?

Comment: Isn't it there on *all* topics? What do you mean by the topic appearing to require attention? It looks like this was just someone's lame attempt to make icons that otherwise have too low of contrast visible. Or do as I suggested a *very* long time ago, and use textual labels and/or actual buttons.

Comment: @CodyGray: _"Same for other topics"_ ;-) It looks like a call for attention, rather than a visibility improvement.

Comment: "completely out of place in SO's slick design" If I remember correctly, the ban note on a banned user’s profile also uses this border styling...

Comment: @CodyGray Maybe you missed it, but they said they've adopted that suggestion in the Nov 29 update: "Topic/Example Menu De-Iconizing: We're going to be converting the menus in Documentation to display more like the menus on Q&A."

Comment: Now that you mention it, @Frank, I didn't miss it. I distinctly remember reading that. But it's easily forgotten, since it is a simple change, promised over a month ago, yet we see no evidence of it. If that ever gets done, it would make this question obsolete.

Comment: @CodyGray: provided they remove the border ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I’m sorry you don’t like our vintage '95 redesign.

[image]

---

**Just kidding!** This was a dev note that accidentally slipped through and made it all the way to production. It *was* a quick hack that I forgot to undo… Oops!

Thanks for reporting this, [red outline should now be gone](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/2084/unary-operators#t=201701031712060971104).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response :D